# Error while uploading pdf file through http request on android 6 appcelerator

Tags: android, mobile, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

When I'm trying to upload a new file from android it works fine, but when I'm trying to upload from an android device working over OS 6 marshmallow after upload it goes onerror method and this is the response:

```
[ERROR] linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/54') failed: Permission denied [fd=54]
[ERROR] linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "libRSDriver.so". Will use given name.
[ERROR] linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/54') failed: Permission denied [fd=54]
[ERROR] linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "libRSCpuRef.so". Will use given name.
[ERROR] linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/54') failed: Permission denied [fd=54]
[ERROR] linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "libblas.so". Will use given name.
```

and this is the code:

```
  var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action: Ti.Android.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
        type: "application/pdf"
    });

    var x = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, "Select");
   $.index.getActivity().startActivityForResult(x, function(e) {
        try {
            var doc = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(e.intent.data);

  var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function() {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log("File uploaded successfully : ", result);
        },
        onsendstream: __.sendstream,
        onerror: function() {
            console.error("Error in upload file : ", this.responseText);
        },
        timeout: 100000000000000000000
    });
    xhr.open("POST", URL);
    xhr.send(doc);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("This is error : " + error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of storage permissions.

Try this:

```
if (Ti.Filesystem.hasStoragePermissions())
{
    // app has storage permission
}
else
{
    Ti.Filesystem.requestStoragePermissions(function(e) 
    {
        if (e.success) 
        {
            // permissions succesfully requested
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I already take permissions for the storage and i can take the file and upload it but after upload the http return onerror closed

Comment: The problem was in the file name file name was in arabic lang when i change it the request success